# Backup Evolution Calendar

Tags: gnome, backup, evolution, calendar

How do I backup only a single calendar in Evolution? It's "On This Computer". I haven't used it in a while, and don't expect to, but I definitely might need to review it sometime in the future. I want to get it out of the way, but restore it later if I need it.

I don't want to just backup and restore all of Evolution to do this. I make regular backups, but that takes a long time and a lot of space. I don't want to restore all of Evolution just to restore and view this calendar later.

Answer (score 2):

As per https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/exporting-data-calendar.html.en right-click on the calendar in the list of calendars and click **Save as**. Available formats are iCalendar format (ICS, recommended), [comma separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (CSV), and [RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) format.  CSV has the advantage of your being able to open it with OpenOffice Calc for analysis, or for editing [before reimport](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/import-single-files.html.en).